# JavaScript event when mouseover AND mousedown

Tags: javascript

Using only Javascript (no jQuery etc) , is there a way I can trigger an event if those two conditions are met?

I currently have a n x m table and I can change the color of each entry with a click. However, I also want to be able to drag the mouse around instead of having to click many times. Is this possible?

This is what I have:

```
<div id ="startButton">
  <button onclick="startGame()">START</button>
</div>
(...)
var tableEntry = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

(...)
function startGame() {
  for(var i = 0, il=tableEntry.length; i < il; i++) {
    tableEntry[i].onmousedown = toggle; //changes color 
  }
}
```

Comment: `shift + [text selection]`

Comment: you should [almost] always use mouse**enter** instead of mouse**over**. To know how they differ, consider this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCWvJ/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since events in JS are "short-lived", you'd have to maintain some shared state variable.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('game-table');
var tableEntry = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
var isToggling = false;

function enableToggle(e) {
  console.log('enableToggle')
  isToggling = true;

  if (e.target !== table) {
    toggle(e);
  }
}

function disableToggle() {
  console.log('disableToggle')
  isToggling = false;
}

function toggle(e) {
  if (isToggling === false) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('toggle:', e.target);

  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
}

function startGame() {
  table.onmousedown = enableToggle;

  for (var i = 0, il = tableEntry.length; i < il; i++) {
    tableEntry[i].onmouseenter = toggle; //changes color 
  }

  table.onmouseup = disableToggle;
}

startGame();
```

```css
table,
td {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
}

td.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="game-table">
  <tr>
    <td>1-1</td>
    <td>1-2</td>
    <td>1-3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2-1</td>
    <td>2-2</td>
    <td>2-3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3-1</td>
    <td>3-2</td>
    <td>3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a variable in your `onmousedown`, and clear it in your `onmouseup`.

Then, in your `onmousemove`, check the variable. If it's set the mouse is down, if not it's up.

You will have to get a bit creative. What you are describing is a drag event. To avoid the default drag behaviour you will need to respond to the `ondragstart` event and return `false` after calling `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to add two event listeners which both have the same functionality

```
function startGame() {
  for(var i = 0, il=tableEntry.length; i < il; i++) {
    tableEntry[i].addEventListener('mousedown', () => toggle());
    tableEntry[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', () => toggle()); 
  }
}
```

Basically `() => toggle()` means `function() { toggle(); }`, so when the button is pressed, then call `toggle`, this is a good way to represent a function, because `toggle` could just as well have been a boolean, then saying `tableEntry[i].addEventListener('mousedown', toggle);` could have been confusing

Comment: Thank you. But in this case, the mouse doesn't have to be down to toggle the entries, right? What I wanted was something like: toggle if (mousedown) or (mouseover and mousedown)

Comment: mouse is always over if you can click on the element, so its redundant to do (mouseover and mousedown)

Comment: I think what @Mil3d wants is "holding down the mouse btn, drag over other cells and toggle them". Sort of like a batch toggle. Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48593751/1343488) below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but when I ran into the same issue, I simply added an eventlistener on document level, which set a global variable to true or false. Example:

```
let tableEntry = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
let squares = Array.from(tableEntry);
let trigger = false;

tableEntry.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (trigger === true){
            //do something
        };
    });
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    trigger = true;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    trigger = false;
});
```

Your mileage may very in terms of how you select your elements for 'tableEntry'. Remember that some selectors return 'live' nodelists, etc.

It might make sense trying to identify the tds by using something like "table.children". Could be more reliable, depending on how your site is structured.

Also note that I have to convert to an array first, in order to make use of the 'forEach' function.